# why we cannot use read() method in java to read an integer

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class  a
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int ch=Integer.parseInt(br.read());
    System.out.print(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); int ch = s.nextInt();`, your code is reading in ascii characters.

Answer (score 2):

`read()` only reads one character and you can read an integer, provided it has only one character.

From the Javadoc for [Reader.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read--)

> Reads a single character. This method will block until a character is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.

What you want is a `Scanner`

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = in.nextInt(); // read multiple characters to parse an integer.
```